# ¿Por qué se usa <E> como tipo de dato dentro de las librerías?

Tags: java

Al usar el jdk e ir a la clase **ArrayList** me topé con esto `public class ArrayList<E>...` y más abajo con métodos así

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    E oldValue = elementData(index);
    elementData[index] = element;
    return oldValue;
}
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
    size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
}
```

Y me gustaría saber por qué y para qué se utiliza se utliliza la **E** si ni tan siquiera es una clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En esos casos se usan tipos genéricos. Se trata de clases genéricas o interfaces.

Esto permite usar esas clases de utilidad (List, Set, ArrayList, Map, etc) y muchas otras como por ejemplo en Spring JPA (CrudRepository, JPARepository, etc) de manera genérica.

Cuando se usan este tipo de clases lo que hace es pasarse en los símbolos de diamante la clase sobre la que se quiere trabajar, por ejemplo, si pensamos en la clase ArrayList para almacenar objetos de, digamos por ejemplo, Stringlo haríamos de este estilo `List<String> asd = new ArrayList<>();`

Ahora le estaríamos diciendo que E va a ser una clase String, de manera que cuando usemos sus métodos, como por ejemplo set al ser uno de los que has puesto, E se va a entender como String. Si lo hicieramos con una clase distinta a la que hemos usado para instanciar `asd` daría error, pero si creamos un nuevo arraylist con otro tipo `List<Integer> asd = new ArrayList<>();` pues podríamos usar Integer pero no String.

Te pongo enlaces a información al respecto: [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)